# Find the source of error in qmake-files

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am new in qmake. I need to port some Windows/QT-based software. I have big experience with CMake, and i am very confused when i see many files, which includes in many other Qmake-files in this project, as far as i know this is normal for qmake. Anyway, i have build error:

```
mkdir -p
mkdir: missing operand
```

Obviously, this is result of some empty variable in command in qmake files. But search in project give me many "mkdir"s in different locations.

My question, is there any way to find which line in `*.pro`, `*.pri`(or even any other qmake-file) is the source of build error?

Comment: isEmpty(VARIABLE ){
  message(variable is empty)
}

Comment: I think you can just use `CMake` to create a Qt-based software. It is not necessary to learn `qmake`. Can you show some examples about qmake files?

Answer (score 1):

You can add sanity checks like the following:

```
isEmpty(VARIABLE ){
  message(variable is empty)
}
```